# When to mark a question as answered

Tags: discussion, answers

Am I right that I only tick an answer to my question if the answer is 'complete'?  There is an answer that is "an answer" but not "the amswer".
ALso, I assume one can only tick one answer to the question?

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [FAQ - How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Comment: Also related (obviously): [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?[(https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

First, stay calm and patient. There is no time slot by which you have to accept an answer. The system may remind you at some point that you may want to check the existing answers to your question, but on the other hand, there are even sites where the community actively discourages “immediate” acceptance.

Accepting an answer is the Stack Exchange way of saying “for me as the asker, this answer solved my problem (best)”. The community may favor one answer, but if another is *better for you*, it’s perfectly ok to accept something different. You may change the acceptance at will, maybe you change your mind or an even better answer is posted at some later time.

So does one answer mean it should be accepted “automatically”? Not necessarily.

- First, you can just wait a bit longer. We’ve occasionally gotten  new (and sometimes very good) answers to “old” posts.
- Second, re-read your post (and the comments): Can it be improved? Clarified?
- Asking the author of the answer for more details may also be a way to get to a truly helpful answer.
- A bounty may draw more attention to your post.

But in the end the decision is yours: if an answer solves your question reasonably well, accept it, if not, it’s ok if you don’t.